# Tell python interpreter to use a interpreter command-line switch in the script itself

Tags: python, command-line, doctest

Is it possible to tell the python interpreter to run my script using specific command line switches.

For example,

If I have doctests enabled, I'd like to add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

to create a self-contained test runner.

However, this requires that I add `-v` switch to run the script:

```
python myscript -v
```

This is not always convenient in an editor like Sublime where the build system defaults to no switches. I know I can create a custom builder but that's suboptimal compared to specifying which switches to use for certain scripts.

Is it possible and if yes, how?

**UPDATE**

Below someone pointed out that the doctest case involves a script flag instead of an interpreter switch. But I really want to know about both cases.

Also although `testmod(verbose=True)` can solve that particular case, I'm still interested in the original question.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux

Comment: @chbchb55 macOS

Comment: Note: the flags for the interpreter itself are not the same as the flags for the script. Running `python myscript -v` passes the `-v` flag to the script, while `python -v myscript` would cause Python to interpret `-v` as a flag for the interpreter itself.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the reminder! I'd like to know both cases. So I'll modify my question.

Comment: Haven't you tried import sys and then sys.argv would contain your input of -v in an array

Comment: @chbchb55 well, that still requires me to send "-v" in my command-line. I'd like to use my IDE to run python on the script but pass the switch in the script itself, sort of like a preprocessor.

Comment: Have you tried importing sys and setting sys.argv to have the -v flag in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of got what I want. On a system with bash shell, I could simply add the following to the top of my script

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3 -m doctest -v
```

and then

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

Don't know how to do that with Windows (maybe wait for the Linux subsystem for Win10), but fortunately I mainly work on macOS.

This works for other command line switches as well.

Answer (score 1):

Pass [`verbose=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.testmod) to `doctest.testmod`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

Messing with the command-line flags is the wrong way to go.

Comment: Thanks. If my title concern is impossible to achieve then I'll mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using environment variables.
e.g.,

```
# from the command line
export VERBOSE_MODE=True

# in the Python code
import os
verbose_mode = os.environ.get('VERBOSE_MODE', False)
```

You could have this be a fallback mechanism if the flag isn't provided on the command line.